# Get a list of names as input from the user and make the first letters uppercase and print each word as a list?

Tags: python

Like so:

```
n = int(input("Enter total number of names:"))

Name = []

print("\n Enter names: ")

for i in range(0, n):
   x = input()
Name.append(x)

print("\n Names are:")

for i in range(0, n):

    print(Name[i].capitalize())
```

But getting an index error

> list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name.append(x)` is outside loop , fix the indentation and you will be fine :

```
n = int(input("Enter total number of names:"))

Name = []

print("\n Enter names: ")

for i in range(0, n):
    x = input()
    Name.append(x)

print("\n Names are:")

for i in range(0, n):
    print(Name[i].capitalize())
```

Answer (score 2):

[@eshirvana has already explained the indentation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427298/2745495), but there is no need to iterate this way.

```
for i in range(0, n):
    print(Name[i].capitalize())
```

Can be written as:

```
for n in Name:
    print(n.capitalize())
```

Also, you don't need to write `range(0, n)`. If you only specify `n`, you will get the same behavior: `range(n)`.

And thirdly, you can use a list comprehension to generate your list of names. `Name` is a poor name for this as it isn't plural and by convention variable names in Python start with a lowercase letter.

```
names = [input() for _ in range(n)]
```

We use `_` rather than something like `i` because this value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
lst = []

lst = [element.capitalize() for element in input("Enter the list name : ").split()]

print(lst)
```

[image: screenshot of code and output]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there a particular point to assigning the empty list to `lst` and then immediately assigning a totally different list to the same variable? Also, why assign a name to it at all rather than just printing the list directly?

Answer (score -1):

Run this it will give the proper value you want:

```py
n = int(input("Enter total number of names:"))

Name = []

list = input ("\n Enter names: ").split()

for i in range(0, n):
    x = input()
    Name.append(x)

for i in range(0, n):
    print(list[i].capitalize())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
n = int(input("Enter total number of names: "))

Name = []

print("Enter names: ")
for i in range(0, n):
    x = input()
    Name.append(x)

print("Names are: ")
for i in Name:
    print(list(i[0].upper() + i[1:]))
```